# How type unspecified range based loop works in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++. So today while solving a problem I wrote a code like this -

```
for(i : {1,2,3}) {
   cout << i << "\n";
}
```

And it compiled and ran just fine. After a while I noticed that I didn't specify any type for "i" and it didn't show me any error. I want to know, how C++ handles this? What type is set for the variable "i" internally?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Range-based for loop without specifying variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697639/range-based-for-loop-without-specifying-variable-type)

Comment: @patatahooligan duplicate comment :))

Comment: Please provide your compiler and version. It doesn't work with the current [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/Tju4Y4), [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/9VuHY8) and [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/NxNxiu) version.

Comment: @arnes lol. I merely flagged it for moderation because I didn't know if you did. The site autogenerated my comment.

Comment: An object of type std::initializer_list<T> is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type const T.

A std::initializer_list object is automatically constructed when:

a braced-init-list is used to list-initialize an object, where the corresponding constructor accepts an std::initializer_list parameter
a braced-init-list is used as the right operand of assignment or as a function call argument, and the corresponding assignment operator/function accepts an std::initializer_list parameter
a braced-init-list is bound to auto, including in a ranged for loop

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a non-standard compliant compiler: [Range-based for loop without specifying variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697639/range-based-for-loop-without-specifying-variable-type)

For example, gcc seems to have dropped support for this unofficial construct between versions 5.5 and 6.1: https://godbolt.org/z/8CJGim